# Apple Push Notification Certificate

Tags: iphone, automation, apple-push-notifications, administration, mdm

I am trying to automate the installing procedure of iPhone apps (i.e) installing apps for around 5000 phones. For this I am planning to deploy an MDM server in Windows Server 2008 containing Active Directory. Once the successful registration of handsets is established the complete control of iPhone can be taken by the admin. I have following doubts:

1) My main objective is to push the apps that are available in the app store, hence Apple Push Notification Certificate will be sufficient to set up my MDM server and install apps?

2) Once the user registers his iOS device will I be able to install/uninstall applications into the device?

3) Can I implement payload mechanisms like AppLock Payload by just having Apple Push Notification Certificate?

Comment: This question is offtopic for stack overflow because it has nothing to do with programming. Please post the question on [server fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [ask different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer further to your questions in comment.

1) Is it is sufficient if i dig more and implement MDM server with the enrolment in Enterprise Developer Program?

Anyway you will need an Enterprise developer program to distribute apps. So go for it.

2) At once, I setup my own MDM solution,will I be able to achieve my goal (Installing Apps Without prompting user)?

Yes indeed. Its just a feature from set of valuable features offered by MDMs. Definitely you can.

3) Will Apple give me more documentation on MDM server and implementing methods when I enrol in Enterprise Developer Program?

No. Enterprise developer program is to distribute your in house apps. That doesn't mean that you can distribute silently without your consent. Thats where the MDM comes into picture. When devices are provisioned to a MDM server you can do MDM operations on enrolled devices. So you need to do a MDM vendor signing request. Thats if you developing such a solution. Otherwise go for MDM solutions already available.

Comment: Thank You! A small clarification:
In question 2, will I be able to install apps available in the app-store too?
In question 3, I am developing this solution to integrate enrolment with AD environment. May be after successful implementation and verification, I will try to act as a third party MDM server. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Yes you can install apps from app store as well. Yes you can act as a 3rd party MDM provider. But you have to obtain above from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comments inline.

1) My main objective is to push the apps that are available in the app store, hence Apple Push Notification Certificate will be sufficient to set up my MDM server and install apps?

No you still need MDM solution for that.

2) Once the user registers his iOS device will I be able to install/uninstall applications into the device?

Yes as long as the MDM vendor supports app installa and uninstalls.

3) Can I implement payload mechanisms like AppLock Payload by just having Apple Push Notification Certificate

I think you have to really read the MDM architecture. Its a separate implementation. Please read on that.

Comment: I ordered for the enrolment of Apple Enterprise Developer Program. And explored more on MDM architecture, my objective is to install apps into the enrolled devises without even prompting the user.

1) Is it is sufficient if i dig more and implement MDM server with the enrolment in Enterprise Developer Program?

2) At once, I setup my own MDM solution,will I be able to achieve my goal (Installing Apps Without prompting user)?

3) Will Apple give me more documentation on MDM server and implementing methods when I enrol in Enterprise Developer Program?

Thank you for your support..

Comment: Yes if you implement a MDM solution you can achieve what you need. From documentation side yes they will give some docs on this. Regarding the implementation I suggest you to go through the below link. There you will find a ruby companion file. What I did was to refer that and convert it to Java which worked for me. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank you! To execute this code will I require MDM certificate? 

And as I understand from [this](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf), the document that you shared help me to install the configuration profile over the air. After which I should send command with APNs for installing/unistalling apps. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you will need a MDM certificate if you need to run iOS. But you can run Android devices without anything if you can configure the Android MDM properly.